# How can we extend this inequality by monotonicity?

Tags: calculus, inequality, monotone-functions

Let $p>1$, $R>0$ and $u:[0,R)\to\mathbb R$ be nonincreasing with $$u(x)\le cx^{\frac2{1-p}}\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in[0,R_0]\tag1$$ for some $c\ge0$ and $R_0\in(0,R)$. Can we extend this inequality to $$u(x)\le\tilde cx^{\frac2{1-p}}\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in[0,R)\tag2$$ for some $\tilde c\ge0$?

Using monotonicity, I only obtain $$u(x)\le u(R_0)\le cR_0^{\frac2{1-p}}\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in[R_0,R)\tag3.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Hint: Let $\overline c=\max \{c, c(\frac {R_0} R)^{\frac 2 {1-p}}\}$. Then  $u(x) \leq cR_0^{\frac 2 {1-p}} \leq \overline c R^{\frac 2 {1-p}}\leq \overline c x^{\frac 2 {1-p}}$ for $R_0 \leq x \leq R$. For $x<R_0$ too the inqulity holds.

Answer (score 0):

OK, we may do this in a trivial way, that is, we'll choose $\tilde{c}$ so big that the inequality will hold. First of all, we have that
$$
u(x)\leq c x^{\frac{2}{1-p}},
$$
for all $x\in [0,R_0)$, and as you noted, using monotonicity
$$
u(x)\leq c R_0^{\frac{2}{1-p}},
$$
for all $x\in [R_0,R)$. As a result, we want to choose $\tilde{c}$ such that $c\leq \tilde{c}$, since then
$$
u(x)\leq cx^{\frac{2}{1-p}}\leq \tilde{c}x^{\frac{2}{1-p}},
$$
on $[0,R_0)$, and also $\tilde{c}x^{\frac{2}{1-p}}\geq cR_0^{\frac{2}{1-p}}$ for all $x\in[R_0,R)$ because then
$$
u(x)\leq cR_0^{\frac{2}{1-p}}\leq \tilde{c} x^{\frac{2}{1-p}},
$$
for all $x\in [R_0,R)$. To do this, observe that if $\tilde{c}x^{\frac{2}{1-p}}\geq c R_0^{\frac{2}{1-p}}$ for all $x\in [R_0, R)$, then
$$
\tilde{c}\geq c\frac{R_0^{\frac{2}{1-p}}}{x^{\frac{2}{1-p}}},
$$
for all $x\in [R_0,R)$, i.e, $
\tilde{c}\geq c\frac{R_0^{\frac{2}{1-p}}}{R^{\frac{2}{1-p}}}$. So take,
$$
\tilde{c}= \max\{c, c\frac{R_0^{\frac{2}{1-p}}}{R^{\frac{2}{1-p}}}\}= c \left(\frac{R_0}{R}\right)^{\frac{2}{1-p}}.
$$